# how to make where condition from an array in mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

I have an associative array like

```
 $where = array('name'=>'name','comp'=>'companyname')
```

This is my query

```
select * from tablename where = $where;
```

And i want to make a mysqli query generate

```
select * from tablename where name = 'name' and comp = 'companyname';
```

Comment: This should help: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo "select * from tablename where ".implode(' AND ' , preg_replace('/^(.*)$/e', ' "$1=\'". $where["$1"]."\'" ',array_flip($where)));
```

Comment: Can you explain that further? Why do you need to echo something? What does that `preg_replace` do?

Comment: preg_replace act upon the flipped array and produces the following array  Array ( [name] => name='name' [companyname] => comp='companyname' ) on whose values we are imploding with ' AND ' delemeter

Comment: Please add such information to the answer itself by editing it, not to the comment section. And still I don't get why you need to use `preg_replace`

Comment: preg_replace is what is going to replace the $1 with key and $where["$1"] with value so that it will formulate the expected array above

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I set the conditions in a string and appended the string onto the end of the query. If you set the WHERE to be 1=1 +'yourstuff', you can build the query dynamically.

```
$queryappnd = '';
foreach($where as $i){
    $column = array_key($i);
    $value = $i;
    $queryappnd .='AND'.$column.'='.$value;
}

$query = "SELECT *
          FROM tablename
          WHERE 1=1".$queryappnd;
```